# How to query the Length/Value limit for a particular VARCHAR field?

Tags: php, mysql, schema

I have looked for a response to this question, as it seems simple enough, but cannot find an answer.

I want to be able to query the maximum amount of characters allowed in a varchar field.  I have set this limit to 225 in the "Length/Value" field and want to be able to recall this number at a later time.

How to I query for this data?

Answer (score 2):

You query INFORMATION_SCHEMA

More on that in the manual:

[The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html)

Comment: Perfect...I knew I was overlooking something.  Thank you Tomas!